# Python Telegram Bot - Youtube Downloader

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, telegram-bot

I Have This Code :

```
import os
import telepot
from pytube import YouTube


def handle(msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    if command.startswith('/start'):
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Hello! Send me a YouTube link to download the video :).')
    else:
        try:
            yt = YouTube(command)
            available_resolutions = []
            for stream in yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4'):
                resolution = f"{stream.resolution}p"
                if resolution not in available_resolutions:
                    available_resolutions.append(resolution)

            if not available_resolutions:
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Sorry, there are no available resolutions for this video.')
            else:
                # Ask user to choose resolution
                keyboard = [[f"{resolution}"] for resolution in available_resolutions]
                reply_markup = {'keyboard': keyboard, 'one_time_keyboard': True}
                bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Please select a resolution:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
                bot._set_inline_keyboard(chat_id, [])

        except Exception as e:
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'Sorry, there was an error processing your request.')
            print(str(e))

    # Wait for user's response
    user_response = ''
    while user_response == '':
        updates = bot.getUpdates()
        for update in updates:
            if 'message' in update and update['message']['chat']['id'] == chat_id:
                user_response = update['message']['text']

    # Download video with chosen resolution
    video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4', resolution=user_response).first()
    video.download()
    bot.sendVideo(chat_id, open(video.default_filename, 'rb'), caption='Here is your video!')
    os.remove(video.default_filename)


TOKEN = 'MY TOKEN BOT'
bot = telepot.Bot(TOKEN)
bot.message_loop(handle)

while True:
    pass
```

When I start the bot and send it the video link, the only message I get is the (Sorry, there was an error processing your request) message. How do I fix this problem?

I tried to solve this problem by changing the quality functions, but no matter what I tried, the problem was not solved.

Comment: What is the result of `print(str(e))`? - also provide a sample video link you use for execute this code.